# How do I search for any day in a month. Searching Feb-19 only gives results for 1st of Feb 2019

Tags: excel-formula

The formula "=SUMIF(A:M,"Feb-19",E:Q)" only sums results for 1st Feb but not for other days in Feb. How can I use this formula for data in any day in any month?

Comment: Would you like the formula to sum by day, or sum the total of the month?

Comment: Hi Jacob, to sum the total of the month. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
=sumproduct((month(A:M)=2)*(E:Q))
```

The `=2` in the formula means february. If you want to sum only values from 2019, you add `*(year(A:M)=2019)` in sumproduct.

EXCEL interprets the 19 as year. So, if you want to sum only specific days, you probably need something like that, if the dates are formatted as text

```
=sumproduct((month(A:M)=2)*(right(A:M,2)*1=19)*(E:Q))
```

and if the dates are properly formatted as date

```
=sumproduct((month(A:M)=2)*(day(A:M)=19)*(E:Q))
```

Answer (score 0):

OverflowStacker's solution will work so long as you are only searching for the month of February (or are OK with changing the formula for each month).

I would you something like this

```
=SUMIFS(A:M,Dates_To_Sum,">="&A1,Dates_To_Sum,"<="&EOMONTH(A1,0))
```

The `=EOMONTH()` finds the end of a month and year combination so it will work across years as well.